# jenkins trigger a build base on changes in just one repo

Tags: git, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jobs

I have a job in jenkins that clone 2 repositories,  A and B,   A is a repo with all the tools to build, move files around, emails etc... and B is a xcode project,

as my understanding is if i have trigger base on Poll SCM * * * * *, any change on the 2 repos A or B will start the job?

I just want to trigger the job when something change on repoB,    then update repo A and B.

thanks =)

Comment: So you do not want to trigger a build when a change is made to repo A, the build tools repo right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipeline in which you can add your upstream dependency for Project A.

Below are steps.

For Project B : Poll SCM ie whenever a change is pushed to GIT

For Project A : Build whenver Project B build gets trigered/builds succesfully , basically add this as downstream for Project B.

Comment: yes i could have job1 with B repository, and when this change will kick job2,  that hold the 2 repos and do the magic,  but is it possible to have all this in just one job?

Comment: yes , you can create these jobs and create a third job and remotely call these jobs using API Token.

Comment: This is probably sub optimal if you have your pipeline in code though. I have a similar setup to this, with all the deployment code in a separate repo. Its in a separate repo as its shared deployment code with a lot of jobs. Splitting it into multiple jobs mean breaking the pipeline code over two repos. Far from ideal to see the correct flow. Especially in blue ocean.